# Apache Nifi GetSolr configuration without Date Field

Tags: solr, apache-nifi

I'm new to Apache Nifi. My requirement is to retrieve data from a solr index, do some processing and store it in a different solr index.

I'm trying to use Nifi GetSolr processor to retrieve the data. GetSolr processor has a mandatory field **Date Field**. however My solr index doesn't have a date/timestamp field in the collections.
Please see a sample document in my solr collection below. [image]

Any workaround to this? Can I use GetSolr without the Date field and use someting like the ***version*** field instead? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

GetSolr is meant to do incremental extraction from an index, meaning each time it runs it finds documents newer than the last time it ran. It can only do that if it can sort the documents by a date/time to compare against it's last execution time.

If you just want a one-time extraction, you may want to use QuerySolr instead.